# Is there a way to use areas when registering controllers with AddApplicationPart

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I am attempting to build a modularized API similar to this [blog post](https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/maybe-its-time-to-rethink-our-project-structure-with-dot-net-6#a-domain-driven-api). What I am trying to do is create a module that sets up an area route and then registers a set of controllers (in separate assemblies) that define a route but also registered to the area. For example if I want a route pattern to be "MyArea/User/Index" then in the MyArea module code would look like:

```
public class MyModule : IModule
{
    public IServiceCollection RegisterModule(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var configuration = AppSettingsHelper.Configuration;

        if (configuration == null) { return services; }

        foreach (var assemblyFileName in configuration
            .GetSection("Modules:MyModule:ApplicationParts")
            .GetChildren()
            .Select(c => c.Value))
        {
            var moduleAssembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
                .GetAssemblies()
                .FirstOrDefault(a => a.FullName == Path.GetFileName(assemblyFileName));

            if (moduleAssembly != null || assemblyFileName == null) continue;

            moduleAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyFileName);
            services.AddMvcCore().AddApplicationPart(moduleAssembly).AddControllersAsServices();
        }

        return services;
    }

    public IEndpointRouteBuilder MapEndpoints(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
    {
        endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
            areaName: "MyArea",
            name: "MyArea",
            pattern: "MyArea/{controller}/{action}"
            );

        return endpoints;
    }
}
```

The assembly that contains the UserController would like like this:

```
[ApiController]
[Area("MyArea")]
[Route("User")]
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Index([FromRoute]int id, [FromBody] UserMode user)
    {
        return Ok();
    }

    [HttpGet()]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Ideally I'd rather not have to specify the Area attribute so that I could configure it to be part of whichever area I want. Possibly in multiple areas if possible, though that's probably not necessary in really just a theoretical desire.

In Program.cs I also have the following code (note that this is just the important parts for brevity):

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.RegisterModules(); // which is an extension method that looks for modules to call the RegisterModule method of any class that implements the IModule interface.

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(name: "areaRoute",
        pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");

app.MapEndpoints();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Status}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Comment: your first app.MapControllerRoute()  would match all routes contain area,there's no need to call the  extension method : MapEndpoints()

Comment: I tried to follow this example: https://geeksarray.com/blog/how-to-use-areas-in-asp-net-core-mvc. One thing I noticed is that, in my example the URL "/User/Index" works but "MyArea/User/Index" does not. Is there a way to see the routing table at run time so I can understand what routes the application is using?